# PySpark - Getting each row of first column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to iterate through every row of the first column of the following output.

Assume table Employees has 3 columns: FirstName, MiddleName, LastName

```
table1=spark.sql("Select * from Employees")
```

[image]

Comment: what do you want to do with that iteration?

Comment: just print each row. so tom, bob, gary would be printed @pltc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table is small enough, then `collect` would be the best `table1.select('FirstName').collect()`

However, keep in mind that `collect` is not scalable, as it uses a single machine instead of distributing the workload to workers.